# Yii Migrations - Down step not working as expected

Tags: yii, frameworks, database-migration

I am using Yii 1.1.x - I have setup a migration to insert a row into a table - this works fine, however I am having issues with the down() method which seems to fail

```
public function down()
{
    //echo "m140115_100413_add_national_text_key_to_national_prizes_config_table does not support migration down.\n";

    $this->delete(
            'national_prizes_config',"key = 'nationaltext'"
    );

    return false;
}
```

Essentially I am trying to simply delete a row in the table where the key is 'nationaltext' - I get an error in the console log when running the Yii migrate down command.

I get the following error (SQL related)

```
You have an error in your syntax...
DELETE FROM national_prizes_config WHERE key = 'nationaltext''
```

I don't understand why it has 2 apostrophies?
Also - why would Yii echo out the 'does not support migration down, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try this -

```
 $this->delete(
        'national_prizes_config','`key` = :val',array(':val'=>'nationaltext')
);
```

or this if you can use the key as an index

```
$this->dropIndex('nationaltext','national_prizes_config');
```

Comment: Both are good shouts - would this be that my column called 'key' is an MYSQL reserved word?

Comment: try the updated answer if you want to use delete - it is in conformity with the docs here - http://yiiapi.com/CDbMigration#delete-detail

Comment: Thanks for the modifying the statement with the backticks

Comment: You are welcome, this was a minute but important detail - anyway best of luck learning Yii, I have never had more fun learning any other PHP framework :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$value='nationaltext';
```

and

```
$this->delete(
            'national_prizes_config',"key = $value"
    );
```

Comment: Bizarre... if I use the 'id' column and just target that instead the above code works, however if I use the 'key' column it errors... really odd.. I will keep having a bash at it

Comment: Ok - the problem is basically I need to have backticks as the key column is a reserved word, does anyone know if I can add backticks to the delete()

Comment: I presumed the dropIndex would only work if the column was setup as an index (in this instance it isn't - and i'm not allowed to mess with the indexes & stuff at work just yet) thanks though really appreciate the answers!! :) Still learning Yii picking it up bit by bit

Comment: alright my comment somehow disappeared from the midst but no issues, let's learn together ;)

Comment: @themosquitokiller I dnt know anything about your comment. I didnt delete it. cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick - thanks to the original answers..

```
    $this->delete(
       'national_prizes_config','`key` = :val',array(':val'=>'nationaltext')
);
```

Comment: Isn't this what my answer was? What's the point of writing it again? :p

Comment: I added the backticks thats all i will give u credit dont worry :)

Comment: and +1 from me for the detail :)

Comment: I'd give you +10 if i could :)